# VueJS reports "Unknown custom element: <IncomeList> - did you register the component correctly?"

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm a junior and trying to make a little exercise from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjV7k7t78Ik income-tracker but ended up error. This is my error that I can't deal with

`[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <IncomeList> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.  found in  ---> <App> at src/App.vue        <Root>`

My App.vue is

```
<template>
  <Header :totalIncome="state.totalIncome" />
  <IncomeList :state="state" @remove-item="removeItem" />
  <Form :state="state" @add-income="AddIncome" />
</template>

<script>
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Form from './components/Form';
import IncomeList from './components/IncomeList';
export default {
  
  setup () {
    const state = reactive({
      income: [],
      sortedIncome: computed(() => {
        let temp = [];
        
        temp = state.income.sort(function (a, b) {
          return b.date - a.date;
        });
        return temp;
      }),
      totalIncome: computed(() => {
        let temp = 0;
        if (state.income.length > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i < state.income.length; i++) {
            temp += state.income[i].value;
          }
          return temp;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      })
    });
    function AddIncome(obj) {
      let d = obj.date.split("-");
      let newD = new Date(d[0], d[1], d[2]);
      state.income = [...state.income, {
        id: Date.now(),
        desc: obj.desc,
        value: parseInt(obj.value),
        date: newD.getTime()
      }]
    }
    function removeItem(id) {
      state.income = state.income.filter(v => v.id != id);
    }
    // Return template data
    return {
      Header,
      IncomeList,
      Form,
      state,
      AddIncome,
      removeItem
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
  background: #EEE;
}
</style>
```

My header.vue is

```
<template>
    <header>
      <h1>Income Tracker</h1>
      <div class="total-income">£{{ totalIncome }}</div>
    </header>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    props: {
      totalIncome: Number
    }
  }
  </script>
  
  <style scoped>
  header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    background-color: #313131;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #FFCE00;
  }
  header h1 {
    color: #EEE;
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  header .total-income {
    font-family: 'Fira Code', 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFCE00;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    min-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  </style>
```

My Form.vue is

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="FormHandler">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Income Description..." v-model="formData.desc" />
      <input type="number" placeholder="Income Value..." v-model="formData.value" />
      <input type="date" placeholder="Income Date..." v-model="formData.date" />
      <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
    </form>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import { reactive } from 'vue';
  export default {
    props: {
      state: Object
    },
    setup (props, { emit }) {
      const formData = reactive({
        desc: null,
        value: null,
        date: null
      });
      function FormHandler () {
        emit("add-income", {
          desc: formData.desc,
          value: formData.value,
          date: formData.date
        });
        
        formData.desc = null;
        formData.value = null;
        formData.date = null;
      }
      // Return template data
      return {
        FormHandler,
        formData
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
  
  <style scoped>
    form {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    form input {
      color: #888;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    form input::placeholder {
      color: #AAA;
    }
    form input:not([type="submit"]) {
      display: block;
      background: #FFF;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      padding: 5px 15px;
    }
    form input[type="submit"] {
      display: block;
      background: none;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: #FFF;
      font-weight: 500;
      text-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      padding: 5px 15px;
      background-color: #FFCE00;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    form input:first-of-type {
      border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
    }
    form input:last-of-type {
      border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
    }
  </style>
```

My IncomeItem.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="income-item">
      <div class="removeItem" @click="removeItem">x</div>
      <div class="desc">
        {{ income.desc }}
      </div>
      <div class="price">
        £{{ income.value }}
      </div>
      <div class="date">
        {{ formattedDate }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    props: {
      income: Object
    },
    setup (props, { emit }) {
      
      let date = new Date(props.income.date);
      let day = date.getDate();
      let month = date.getMonth();
      let year = date.getFullYear();
      let formattedDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
      function removeItem () {
        emit("remove-item", props.income.id);
      }
      return {
        formattedDate,
        removeItem
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
  
  <style scoped>
    .income-item {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      padding: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
      background-color: #FFF;
      border-radius: 8px;
      max-width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto 30px;
    }
    .removeItem {
      color: #EF2D2D;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 1;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 15px;
    }
    .desc {
      color: #666;
      flex: 1 1 100%;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .price {
      color: #666;
      min-width: 100px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .date {
      color: #666;
      text-align: right;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  </style>
```

My IncomeList.vue is

```
<template>
    <div class="income-list">
      <IncomeItem v-for="obj in state.sortedIncome" :key="obj.id" :income="obj" @remove-item="removeItem" />
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import IncomeItem from './IncomeItem';
  export default {
    props: {
      state: Object
    },
    setup (props, { emit }) {
      function removeItem(id) {
        emit( 'remove-item', id );
      }
      return {
        IncomeItem,
        removeItem
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
  
  <style scoped>
    .income-list {
      margin-top: 30px;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the setup() hook you have to register the components you want to use like this:

```
export default {
  components: {
      Header,
      IncomeList,
      Form
  },
  props: { someProps },
  setup(props) {
...
```

Alternatively you can use `<script setup>` where you don't have to register them like this: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to register this IncomeItem as a component here for the VUE to understand it is a component.

Add following into your IncomeList.vue:

```js
<script>
import IncomeItem from "./IncomeItem.vue";
export default {
    props: {
        state: Object
    },
// add this below line as an component
    components: { IncomeItem },
// above component. you need to register this IncomeItem as a component here for the VUE to understand it is a component.
    setup() {
        return {
            IncomeItem
        }
    }
}

</script>
```